# create multiple df in loop based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, slice

I need to create multiple dataframes from slices of a bigger dataframe in pandas based on a condition. The different dataframes have to be named on the basis of some row values of the big dataframe.

This is the big dataframe:

```
 Id  Valore
ID554    53.0
ID554    43.0
ID522    42.0
ID522    32.0
ID566    26.0
```

therefore the different dataframes have to be named ID554, ID522, ID566 and so on.
I have tried this:

```py
id=df['Id'].unique()
for a in id:
 a=df.loc[(df['ID']==a)]
```

it does not work though..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.groupby`:

```
dataframes = {}
for name, g in df.groupby("Id"):
    dataframes[name] = g

# print the data:
for k, v in dataframes.items():
    print("Name:", k)
    print("-" * 80)
    print(v)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Name: ID522
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Id  Valore
2  ID522    42.0
3  ID522    32.0

Name: ID554
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Id  Valore
0  ID554    53.0
1  ID554    43.0

Name: ID566
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Id  Valore
4  ID566    26.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":["ID554","ID554","ID522","ID522","ID566"],"Valore":[53,43,42,32,26]})

for i in df.Id.unique():
    exec(f"{i} = df[df.Id == i]")
```

Following code will make different dataframes and save it in different variables with the name of its ID.

OUTPUTS:

```
print(ID522)

          Id  Valore
    2  ID522      42
    3  ID522      32

print(ID554)

       Id  Valore
    0  ID554      53
    1  ID554      43

print(ID566)

       Id  Valore
    4  ID566      26
```

Comment: Using `exec` is almost always a bad idea.  There are too many ways to go wrong.

Comment: Requirement is having multiple sub dataframes with the name of ID.

Comment: Another approach can be making a dict to store those dataframes but that is not required